# Trouble hooking into the right wp-query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hook into the [Cherry Team Members plugin](https://github.com/CherryFramework/cherry-team-members) via my child theme's functions.php file and modify the `orderby`, `meta-key`, and `order` to what I want.

I've already successfully accomplished my end goal by editing the plugin files themselves [as outlined here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sort-team-members/) by modifying [this file specifically](https://github.com/CherryFramework/cherry-team-members/blob/8410014ebdaf45ec8bac01ac3cfc982afbf9116a/public/includes/class-cherry-team-data.php), but I know that if I update the plugin, my changes will be lost. Therefore, I would like to be able to hook into this query and make my modifications using the `pre_get_posts` action so that future plugin updates will not affect this change.

Below is what I've tried in my child theme's functions.php, but I think I am selecting the wrong query, as this code breaks my site.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_team_query' );
function modify_team_query( $query ) {

    // Check if on frontend and main query is modified
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] = 'team' ) {

        $query->set('meta_key', 'last_name');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value title');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to select only the query that happens when I return the `[cherry-team]` shortcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need to remove the `$query->is_main_query()`. The "main query" is set when WordPress decides what to query for the current Request URI (a certain page, post, category, etc.) - and since this is returned via a shortcode, I'd wager that `$query->is_main_query()` is returning false.

Also, you're attempting to *assign* the post type in your `if` statement:

```
$query->query_vars['post_type'] = 'team'
```

should instead use a *comparison* operator:

```
$query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'team'
```

Comment: I figured out the `==` operator typo just before you posted, but removing the `is_main_query` solved it for me. Works perfectly!! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

try to create your function in a separate php file, and include that php file into the plugin main file. keep a backup of this file. So, if your plugin is updated, you only have to add one line of code into the main plugin file to load your custom coded function.

Comment: You shouldn't be editing plugin files _ever_ without forking them so they aren't updated. If the question ever arises of "Should this plugin file be edited?" The answer is no. There _are_ exceptions to the rule where something can't be hooked/changed - but that's where you either need to fork the plugin, find another that better suits your needs, or write your own functionality. Editing even single lines in core or plugin files is just asking for trouble. I'm _still_ fixing "past me's" mistakes of editing plugin files when it comes time to update plugins and themes.